# "No password hashes loaded" John does not recognise my hashes

Tags: passwords

I am trying to learn how `john` works. I made a password-protected `rar` archive, and written that password inside a file named `pass.txt`.

I used `rar2john` to build the hash:

```
# more test.hash 
test.rar:$rar3$*0*c15839e058bb28a3*9d55925bdd33618f3e02f8b7004faab8
```

However, when I try to run `john`, I get an error message:

```
# john --format=rar --wordlist=pass.txt test.rar
Warning: invalid UTF-8 seen reading test.rar
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

I tried with and without the `--format` and `--wordlist` options.

I read [John The Ripper's FAQ](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/FAQ.shtml) but nothing helped me.

I saw that the format `rar` was supported on [Pentest Monkey](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/john-the-ripper-hash-formats). I even tried the example they gave, but `john` keeps telling me the same thing.

Any idea?

Comment: The "invalid UTF-8" leads me to believe that there's something wrong with your file encoding. You can use Vim to change file encodings by using `set encoding=utf-8`

Comment: Might it be such a small mistake as you using the rar file as input instead of the hash file? Could you show the output for `john --format=rar --wordlist=pass.txt test.hash`?

Answer (score 5):

```
john --format=rar --wordlist=pass.txt test.rar
```

You're telling `john` to look in the original .rar file for password hashes.  John the Ripper does not understand how to parse .rar files (that's what `rar2john` is for); you need to pass the file containing the extracted password hash:

```
john --format=rar --wordlist=pass.txt test.hash
```

Answer (score -1):

Using John the Ripper (JtR), you could find your RAR file's password with these sample commands:

```
rar2john.exe example.rar > hash.txt
john.exe --wordlist=rockyou.txt --rules=All hash.txt
```