# John the ripper is not identifying hashes

Tags: hash, password-cracking, zip

I'm attempting to use JTR against a password protected zip. 
I have created the hash file using:
`zip2john filename.zip > filename.hash`
 and i get a successful output:
`file.txt is using AES encryption, extrafield_length is 11`

But when I attempt to run:
`john filename.hash`
I get:
`Using default input encoding: UTF-8`
`No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)`

I have checked the FAQ and also checked a related post at ["No password hashes loaded" John does not recognise my hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102737/no-password-hashes-loaded-john-does-not-recognise-my-hashes) but no luck

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of filename.hash? Preferably obfuscate the actual hash so it is not revealed to the internett.

Comment: Which version of JtR are you using? Cracking zip require the community enhanced versions of JtR a.k.a the jumbo versions.

Comment: The contents of filename.hash are `filename.zip:$zip$*0*1*095d6ee25adfb2bb*ea14`. It's not an important hash so i've provided the original hash as is. It's only a test of JTR. I'm using JTR Version: `John the Ripper password cracker, version 1.8.0.6-jumbo-1-bleeding_omp [linux-gnu 64-bit SSE2-autoconf]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with your JTR installation. I suggest reinstalling/recompiling and trying again. When I run the hash you supplied in the comments, I get the following:

```
Loaded 1 password hash (zip [32/32])
```

It is currently cracking against a 160mb wordlist.

Comment: I tried `apt-get install --reinstall john` on Kali Linux then `john filename.hash` but i'm still getting the same error. The default version on Kali Linux is the Jumbo Version `John the Ripper password cracker, version 1.8.0.6-jumbo-1-bleeding_omp [linux-gnu 64-bit SSE2-autoconf`. Is this version sufficient for cracking this hash?

Comment: I don't know. I am testing on Windows with the following version: 1.7.9-jumbo-5 [win32-cygwin-x86-sse2i] . Try downgrading your version.

Comment: Confirmed. This appears to be an issue with JTR versions 1.8.0+. I installed JTR 1.7.9 Jumbo and now everything is working.

Comment: Going through the Comp TIA+ Security training and this is one of the lab exercises.  Don't have a lot of experience using Linux, how to install an older version of JTR?  Currently running 1.8.0.6 and having the same problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. Version 1.8.0.6-jumbo-1-0kali9

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this response is still useful but as of Feb 19, John 1.8.0.13-jumbo-1-bleeding works. I was previously using 1.8.0.6-jumbo-1-bleeding which had that problem.
You can update it easily with

```
apt-get install john
```

Historical versions of John can be found here

https://openwall.info/wiki/john/custom-builds?do=revisions

https://download.openwall.net/pub/projects/john/contrib/linux/historical/

You don't really have to install it, just unzip and execute it from the "run" subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You need John the Ripper jumbo release to crack hashes generated from zip2john (https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/FAQ.shtml).
You could download John the Ripper jumbo release from this webpage: https://www.openwall.com/john/ .

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the format like this

john --format=crypt yourFile.txt

I refer to this link to find my hash format

http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/john-the-ripper-hash-formats